# Mask folium map outside of geojson border

Tags: python, dictionary, geojson, folium

I may be wording this incorrectly, and maybe that's why I'm not pulling up any solutions on this, but I'd like to clip or mask the folium map *outside* my geojson file border to make the elements of the map pop out more.  can that be done?  Here is my code:

```
style1 = {'fillColor': '#228B22', 'color': '#FFFFFF','fillOpacity': '.6',
              'opacity':'0', 'stroke':'False'}
    m = folium.Map(
            location=[34.02571149, -118.366837957],
            tiles="Stamen Toner",
            zoom_start=11
            )
    folium.GeoJson("Myfile.geojson", 
                   name="geojson",style_function=lambda x:style1).add_to(m)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
    
    m.save("index.html")
    m
```

Is there a tag I can add to the style or the geojson or the map that would do that?  Mask all map features outside of the geojson?